# Gmap distance between point and path server side

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I'd like to calculate the distance between a set of points (path) and a single point in server side (Node.js) app. So, I digged in internet I didn't find an interesting solution except that I find what I am looking for, but for the front-end. ***polyline.isLocationOnEdge()***.
Is there a way to use it on the server side, or an alternative to it.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question how are points represented and what does a path mean?

Comment: Well, the point is a geopoint with {lat, lng} attributes, and the path is a set of geopoints (google maps stuff)

Comment: turf.along should help. 
Its mentioned on the first page of the documentation here. 
Link: http://turfjs.org/docs/

Comment: @vijaykrishnavanshi
If you are talking about _along_ function then you didn't grasp the idea. I'd like to verify if a point is in a certain distance from a polyline (Linestring, path). The closest function on turf is _booleanPointOnLine_ but this verify if a point in on a line only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I looked for Google isLocationOnEdge function, and I found the Java implementation for it [PolyUtil](https://github.com/jefersondeoliveira/android-hackathon/blob/e92491bb422a605c9165c10318f0e025d9cb5697/google-maps-utils/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L167).
Then the rest is to convert the code to nodejs Javascript code, and it worked fine.